# What library should I link to get proper definition of WinRT's "EXTERN_C const IID IID___x_ABI_*"

Tags: c, windows-runtime

[Here](https://github.com/Triang3l/HbEngine/blob/master/HbInput_Windows.c#L46) is some **raw C** code using `windows.gaming.input.h` API:

```
    HSTRING gamepadClassName;
    if (FAILED(WindowsCreateString(RuntimeClass_Windows_Gaming_Input_Gamepad,
            HbArrayLength(RuntimeClass_Windows_Gaming_Input_Gamepad) - 1, &gamepadClassName))) {
        Error("Failed to create a WinRT string reference for Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad class name.");
    }
    static IID const gamepadStaticsInterfaceID = { 0x8BBCE529, 0xD49C, 0x39E9, { 0x95, 0x60, 0xE4, 0x7D, 0xDE, 0x96, 0xB7, 0xC8 } };
    if (FAILED(RoGetActivationFactory(gamepadClassName, &gamepadStaticsInterfaceID, &HbInputi_Windows_Gamepad_Statics))) {
        Error("Failed to get the IGamepadStatics activation factory for Windows.Gaming.Input.Gamepad.");
    }
    WindowsDeleteString(gamepadClassName);
```

Is there any way to get rid of this **`gamepadStaticsInterfaceID`** GUID definition in code? I tried to use `IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CGaming_CInput_CIGamepadStatics` declared in  `windows.gaming.input.h` header but then then I have `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CGaming_CInput_CIGamepadStatics`.
What lib should I link to properly define `IID___x_ABI_CWindows_CGaming_CInput_CIGamepadStatics`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be not included in the SDK.

Typically, this would come from a lib like uuid.lib. However, I see no evidence that the IID's for Windows.Gaming (or other winrt types that I've spot-checked) are supplied this way in any library in the Windows SDK. C usage is supported for winrt types, but very lightly used.

I'll open a bug to track this when I get back into the office tomorrow. For now, your only option is to define the GUID in your code as you've done here.

Ben Kuhn (MSFT)

Comment: Yes, I already tried to link uuid.lib and OneCore.lib, OneCoreUap.lib. None helped.
Thank you for answer. Keep me in touch if you have any update on this.

Comment: I can now confirm definitively that they're not shipped in the SDK. There are a very small number of C users consuming winrt types, and the workaround that you're doing is the recommended approach. I've noted this omission in my team's backlog, but I can't commit to any time. If you need more than a few, you could hack up the ABI writer in the xlang project here to produce a full set of definitions from a winmd file: https://github.com/Microsoft/xlang/tree/master/src/tool/abi. If we do get time to add these to the kits, that's probably where we would start as well.